# How do I find who shut down a computer remotely?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, shutdown

Recently, someone at my high school used the command prompt trick where you type: shutdown -i and enter the computers you want to remotely turn off.

Is there a way I could/could have found the computer that did this?

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer of a system that got shutdown and see if something in there says the source system that did it.

Comment: How do some schools not block this????? I thought `shutdown -i` was a useless prank that hasn't worked in years lol. Guess there's still some fun places

Answer (score 0):

Please check the event log 1074:USER32 events, are generated whenever a user Shutdown/Reboots the machine, which include the shutdown type: power off or restart as well as other details shown under General.

Find a screenshot from my windows 10 as reference: IP address was the remote computer I run command to shut down 330VM machine.

[image]